# Why shouldn't I use catch() to handle errors in React useEffect API calls?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

On this page of the React docs:

https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html

A code comment says...

> Note: it's important to handle errors here instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow exceptions from actual bugs in components.

...about handling errors in the second argument to the second `.then` after `fetch`. The complete snippet from the docs is:

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.example.com/items")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result);
        },
        // Note: it's important to handle errors here
        // instead of a catch() block so that we don't swallow
        // exceptions from actual bugs in components.
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
  }, [])
```

It doesn't elaborate on this advice, and I've seen many examples of working React code using `catch` to handle errors from API calls. I've tried Googling but can't find any clarification.

Could someone please give me a more detailed explanation as to why I shouldn't use `catch` to deal with errors that arise when making a `fetch` API call in a `useEffect` hook?

Or are there some situations when it's ok to do so, but others when it's not?

What is meant by "swallow exceptions [...] in  components" ?

Does this rule/guideline apply to all of React, or just to API calls?

Or just to the `useEffect` hook or `componentDidMount` lifecycle method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is a copy-and-paste error of the example's author.
The first example uses the component state of a class based component: `this.setState()` causes a synchronous re-render (or at least this was the case with react v15.0 in 2016, not sure if it holds true today). Therefore the warning comment and the use of the second arg to `.then(onResolve, onReject)` is justified.
The second example uses the `useState` hook of a function component: `setState` causes no *synchronous* re-render only an asynchronous re-render. Therefore the warning comment and the use of the second arg to `.then(onResolve, onReject)` is **not** justified.

To illustrate this: with `useState` hooks you can call multiple updaters and they all will only take effect in one re-render.

```
const [a, setA] = useState();
const [b, setB] = useState();
const [c, setC] = useState();

const updateState = () => {
  setA('foo');
  setB('bar');
  setC('buz');
  // will only cause one single re-render
}
```

and therefore its perfectly fine to use catch

```
useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.example.com/items")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setItems(result);
        }
      )
      .catch(
        (error) => {
          setIsLoaded(true);
          setError(error);
        }
      )
  }, [])
```

Comment: So if I've understood correctly, that comment was left in the example by mistake and there is absolutely no reason why I shouldn't use catch() to handle errors in React useEffect API calls.
Great, thank you.

Comment: Yes exactly. You can use `.catch()` and I think it enhances clarity of the code.

Answer (score 18):

Everything I can find on this seems to link back to [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/7617#issuecomment-247710003) circa 2016. I'll quote verbatim from there since it doesn't appear to have been covered on Stack Overflow before and it explains things pretty thoroughly:

---

```
.then(() => {
  this.setState({ loaded: true })
})
.catch(()=> { 
  console.log('Swallowed!') 
});
```

> Your `catch()` handler is going to catch any error thrown in the `then()`
> chain before it, including the one caused by a `render()` due to a
> `setState()` call.
>
> Even if you don't use `setState` directly, you may have the same problem
> if some other code you call uses it (for example, a Redux `dispatch()`).
>
> If you don’t want to catch errors resulting from `setState()`, and want
> to only catch network failures (let’s imagine your `Promise.resolve()`
> is actually a `fetch()`), you want to use the second `then()` argument
> instead:

```
componentDidMount() {
  Promise.resolve()
  .then(() => {
      this.setState({ loaded: true })
  }, (err) => {
    console.log('An error occurred (but not in setState!)', err);
  });
}
```

> In this case, unless you `catch()` later in the chain, the error in
> `render()` will be uncaught and, with a good Promise polyfill (or with
> native Promises in Chrome and maybe other browsers), displayed.

---

**Edit**: following the answer from @Martin I went and tested this, and I can confirm that this no longer appears to be a relevant concern. Render errors from `setState` are not caught in any version of React from v16.0 onwards, and since `useState` was only introuduced in v16.8, it doesn't seem possible that this could ever have been an issue for hooks.

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/catching-react-render-errors-in-cdm-ihtmc?file=/src/App.js) which demonstrates the original issue in the older versions of React.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question and for testing and confirming the other answer.